# Conditionally perform an action with redis

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

i want to create a function that takes a key (string) as input. If key is existent within the cache the function will return true, else it will add the key to cache and return false. I am very new to redis so i appreaciate all help.

```
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

const lookup = (key) => {
client.get(key, (err, reply) => {
if(err) return err;
if(reply !== null) return true;
if(reply === null) {
  client.set(key, 1);
  return false;
}
```

})
}

```
const key = 'key';
const doesKeyExist = lookup(key);
console.log(doesKeyExist);
```

Comment: you are not returning anything from `lookup`

Comment: Yes i know, because i do not know how to access reply outside of callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `node-redis` doesn't support promises, you need to pass a callback to your function, or otherwise look at how to use [util.promisify](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis#promises)

Solution without `util.promisify`:

```js
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

const lookup = (key, callback) => {
  client.get(key, (err, reply) => {
    if(err) callback(err, null);
    if(reply !== null) callback(null, true);
    if(reply === null) {
      client.set(key, 1);
      callback(null, false);
    })
}

const key = 'key';
lookup(key, (err, doesKeyExist) => {
  console.log(doesKeyExist);
});
```

Comment: Sorry for adding up an extra question, but is it possible to attach the calling of function "lookup()" to a variable that can be accessed (i get undefined)? As i want the outer return to change depending on what happens within the lookup function.

Comment: I get what you mean, the closest you can do is use `async`/`await` syntax, for that you  need to return a `Promise` from `lookup`.